# Changing a property of an object that's inside an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I've got an array of simple objects, I'm filtering the array and am wanting to change one of the properties in one of the objects—in this case the `before` property in the object where `name = author` is supposed to change to `XX`. the `console.log` on line `51` of the JS is showing that change, but when I log the entire new array of objects (`newLayout`) on line `54`, I'm still getting the original property value.

```js
function buttonClick() {
  const layout = [{
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Author',
      name: 'author',
      before: '',
      after: ''
    },
    {
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Title',
      name: 'title',
      before: ', ',
      after: ''
    },
    {
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Editor',
      name: 'editor',
      before: ', ed. ',
      after: ''
    },
    {
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Translatator',
      name: 'trans',
      before: ', trans. ',
      after: ''
    }
  ]
  const payload = {
    layout: layout,
    name: 'author',
    value: 'XX'
  }
  action(payload)
}

function action(payload) {
  const name = payload.name
  let newLayout = payload.layout.filter((ele) => {
    let newEle = {}
    if (ele.name === name) {
      newEle = { ...ele,
        before: payload.value
      }
    } else {
      newEle = { ...ele
      }
    }
    console.log(newEle)
    return newEle
  })
  console.log(newLayout)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using `.filter()`? I think it should be `.map()` instead.

Comment: `filter()` returns the elements of the original array. The value of the callback function is just used for truth-testing. Since any object is truthy, you're basically doing `.filter((ele) => true)`

Comment: @Pointy that's what I had wrong, now I understand `.filter()` vs `.map()` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.filter() does not return an element, it returns true or false, depending on if you want to keep the element or not. If you wanna keep your code mostly the same, this works:

e; I will say as a word of warning, this does modify the original object, so there is not much of a point to make a new one.

```js
function buttonClick() {
  const layout = [{
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Author',
      name: 'author',
      before: '',
      after: ''
    },
    {
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Title',
      name: 'title',
      before: ', ',
      after: ''
    },
    {
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Editor',
      name: 'editor',
      before: ', ed. ',
      after: ''
    },
    {
      type: 'txt',
      display: 'Translatator',
      name: 'trans',
      before: ', trans. ',
      after: ''
    }
  ]
  const payload = {
    layout: layout,
    name: 'author',
    value: 'XX'
  }
  action(payload)
}

function action(payload) {
  const name = payload.name
  let newLayout = payload.layout.filter((ele) => {
    if (ele.name === name) {
      ele.before = payload.value
    }
    return true
  })
  console.log(newLayout)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Test</button>
```